# create multiple txt files from a txt file

Tags: java, arrays, text-files, readfile

I have a txt file like:

```
ABC

ABC/DEF

    dxcxvcnsaapd - xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
ABC/DEF/:7300000

    zxccdnsavcbapd - xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
ABC/DEF/:2BC0000

    dvcbvbvnsaapd - xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
ABC/DEF/XYZ

    dnsavccbnbapd - xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Test

    dnsavccbnbapd - xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    dnsavccbnbapd - xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    dnsavccbnbapd - xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    dnsavccbnbapd - xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Test/abcd

    dnsavccbnbapd - xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    dnsavccbnbapd - xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    dnsavccbnbapd - xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    dnsavccbnbapd - xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Test22

    dnsavccbnbapd - xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    dnsavccbnbapd - xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    dnsavccbnbapd - xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    dnsavccbnbapd - xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

and I want to create txt files with title **ABC, Test, Test22** and write the lines below in it with Java. I mean for example I need a txt. file with title **ABC** and I want to write the following lines inside it.

```
ABC

ABC/DEF

    dxcxvcnsaapd - xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
ABC/DEF/:7300000

    zxccdnsavcbapd - xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
ABC/DEF/:2BC0000

    dvcbvbvnsaapd - xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
ABC/DEF/XYZ

    dnsavccbnbapd - xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Would you please advice me on how to come up with a solution ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) write code 2) compile code 3) test code 4) debug code. You do #1-3, we'll MAYBE help with #4

Comment: @D.Suslu: You should show us some effort to solve your problem on your own. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). As it is your question is too broad and will be downvoted and eventually closed.

Answer (score 0):

Following these steps with trial and error. You will be able to solve your problem.

## 1 [Reading a plain text file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716503/reading-a-plain-text-file-in-java)

## 2 [How do I create a file and write to it in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885173/how-to-create-a-file-and-write-to-a-file-in-java)